# Typing the 'e' key brings the emoji menu when using Pyautogui with Chrome

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, pyautogui, macos-ventura

I was planning to create an automatization using pyautogui. When I want to write a website address to Chrome's address bar via `typewrite()`function of Pyautogui, the letter 'e' brings the emoji menu. Therefore, it cannot type the address. How can I fix it? Does anybody encountered this situation?

```
def navigate_to_cancel_requests():

    pyautogui.typewrite('e', interval=0.5)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
```

This writes it to an address bar. And there is no cmd or ctrl button down when using this function.

I tried both `typerwrite()`and `write()`functions. I did not use any keyDowns.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with another program.  Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I know this in not the best solution, but it helped me.

Just before pyautogui.write() I used pyautogui.keyUp('Fn')

```
def navigate_to_cancel_requests():
    pyautogui.keyUp('Fn')
    pyautogui.typewrite('e', interval=0.5)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me when on OS X I was using pyautogui.hotkey('up')